# How do I remove a single special character from a file in Linux?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have this JSON file and I am trying to remove `[` and only that from the file, but I am having a difficult time trying to figure this out and need some help.

Current:

```
[{"_id":"DATA"}
```

Expected:

```
{"_id":"DATA"}
```

It's an extremely large file; I can't edit it manually but `[` appears only once.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a MCVE showing concise, testable sample input, expected output, and what you've tried so far. See [ask].

Comment: @prajwal, can you show us what you've tried? This isn't a difficult thing, so any of the tools that can edit files can do this. Have you tried any of them? Did they not work? Also, is the `[` _always_ and _only_ the first character of the first line of the file? Does `cut -c 2- file > newfile` give you what you need for example?

Comment: Didn't you just ask this same question recently but with more context that showed you don't need to do this at all (you had an earlier pipeline with sed command(s) that was doing part of the job but it could all be replaced with one trivial awk command)?

Answer (score 4):

Use `sed`:

```bsh
sed -i '1s/^\[//' file
```

or if your version of `sed` does not have `-i`:

```bsh
sed '1s/^\[//' file > file.tmp && mv file.tmp file
```

**Explanation:**

- `-i` Edit file in place (Alternative: write output to `.tmp` file and move back to original name).
- `1` in first line, do the following:
- `s/pattern/replacement/modifiers` substitute pattern with replacement and use the given modifiers.
  In your case: pattern is `^\[` for match `]` in the very beginning of the line `^` with empty replacement and no modifiers.

Comment: If the `[` appears only once, you could even generalize to just `sed -i 's/\[//' file` if we're not sure it's on the first line only.

Comment: All you really need to do this is `tr -d '['` but I think the OP is trying to put a bandaid on a wounded script...

Answer (score 0):

In the Vim editor, you can simply use the following in command mode

```
%s/\[//g
```